# How to use @ClosureParams for closure that expects two parameters?

Tags: groovy, closures

I had a method that have a closure as one of its parameters and I wished to cast the input closure's param with the `@ClosureParam` annotation:

```
def <T> List<T> randomInstances( final int size, final Builder<T> builder, 
                                 @ClosureParams( SecondParam.FirstGenericType ) 
                                  final Closure<Void> postProcessor = null ) {

        ( 0..<size ).collect {
            def instance = builder.build()
            if ( postProcessor ) {
                postProcessor( instance )
            }
            instance
        }
    }
```

Now, I've added the second method that will do the same, but the closure will receive two params:

```
def <T> List<T> randomInstances( final List<?> listToIterate, 
                                 final Builder<T> builder,
                                 @ClosureParams( FirstParam.FirstGenericType ) 
                                 @ClosureParams( SecondParam.FirstGenericType ) 
                                 final Closure<Void> postProcessor = null )
```

I'm pretty sure that two `@ClosureParams` in line it's wrong use case. But I've not found the way how to pass two closure's parameters "declaration" to the method signature.
Is it possible?? Could anybody help??

P.S. When I used the annotation, I had expect not only describing for future reader, but also to help IDEA to infer the param's type. But I didn't get that result?? What I do wrong, or IDEA just don't support this feature??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can use [`groovy.transform.stc.FromString`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.15/html/api/groovy/transform/stc/FromString.html) with `["T,U", "T"]` options:

```
@ClosureParams(value = groovy.transform.stc.FromString, options = ["T,U", "T"])
```

And here is a short example:

```groovy
class Lists {
  static <T,U> List<T> randomInstances(List<U> listToIterate, final Builder<T> builder, @ClosureParams(value = FromString, options = ["T,U", "T"]) final Closure<T> postProcessor = null) {
    (0..<listToIterate.size()).collect {
      def instance = builder.build()
      if (postProcessor) {
        postProcessor(instance)
      }
      instance
    }
  }
}
```

And here is what what IDE param suggestion looks like for given method definition:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very helpful!!
But:
first and second params have different generics.
So, it works for: `def <T, U> List<T> randomInstances( List<U> listToIterate,  Builder<T> builder, @ClosureParams( value = FromString, options = 'T, U' )  Closure<Void> postProcessor)`. But the method could be also called with single-param closure, and in this case of usage (`{ p -> ... }`) the param is recognized just like `Object` (adding `@ClosureParams( value=FromString, options='T' don't help).

Comment: @ВадимУстименко To support two different closure params you can specify options with a list like `["T,U", "T"]`. I've updated the answer to explain this use case as well.

Comment: Check two things: 1) does `builder` variable has a generic type specified (e.g. if you pass` new Builder()` then `ins` is `Object`, while thing like `new Builder<String>` should make `ins` type of `String`), and 2) you execute `postProcessor(instance)` so there is no second parameter passed - Groovy cannot infer what kind of type you expect. Passing e.g. `it` as a second parameter should reveal its type.

Comment: very grateful. But here becomes one more problem: If works perfectly if use use the method direct from the class (`new MyClass().randomInstances(...)`). But in my code `MyClass` marked with `@Delegate`, so, I just write `randomInstances(...)`, and all my params are `Object`s.((